# Has the Paddington Water Taxi reopened

Tags: london, england

We have seen various sources indicating that the Paddington Water Taxis (10-Minute free boat rides on the Paddington Basin) were planning to resume after Covid this spring.

Does anyone know if this is actually the case? We have not been able to find any direct information newer than 2019.

Comment: The Paddington Water Taxi is run by GoBoat UK. Multiple contact methods are shown on their [GoBoat's main page](https://goboat.co.uk). Have you asked GoBoat directly?

Comment: That website does not mention free 10-minute rides, but from £95 for the first hour. What are your 'various sources'?

Comment: @WeatherVane [The Paddington Partnership](https://thisispaddington.com/article/paddington-water-taxi) states that "Paddington's free Water Taxi was temporarily suspended due to Covid restrictions. We'll be back in spring 2021 for free 10-minute journeys on the canal between Merchant Square and Paddington Central."

Comment: It looks like the free Paddington Water Taxi might only be available on special occasions these days. It was provided for a [week in August](https://twitter.com/inpaddington/status/1561651484923777026) in honor of National Dog Day.

Comment: @travelgasm Thanks for posting the link faster than I was able. Yes, that is the most official link I know of, another is here: [At time of writing, this service has been suspended due to Covid and winter, but we hope to see it back when the new season begins in April 2022.](https://londonist.com/london/things-to-do/london-boat-trips-rides-ferries)